# Can I loop through a list of filter values, and start a job with each of them, in Circle CI?

Tags: parallel-processing, circleci

Similar to [How start identical jobs with different parameters in parallel execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624829/how-start-identical-jobs-with-different-parameters-in-parallel-execution) but for CircleCI not Jenkins.

I have a working Circle CI config. One of my jobs is `run-tests`. It takes a parameter called `filter` which is passed to the command that actually runs our tests (`jest` in this case).

```
  run tests:
    description: Run backend tests
    # https://circleci.com/docs/reference-2-1/#docker
    parameters:
      filter:
        description: "Test filter for jest"
        default: ""
        type: string
    executor: full-backend

    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: /home/circleci/project

      - run:
          # Note the 'circle_test' DB is already created on the DB image
          name: Run DB migration
          command: |
            cd /home/circleci/project; set -o allexport; cp .env.circleci .env; source .env
            npm run typeorm -- migration:run

      - run:
          name: Run tests
          # 30GB of 32GB total per resource_class above
          command: |
            cd /home/circleci/project; set -o allexport; cp .env.circleci .env; source .env
            node --max_old_space_size=30720 ./node_modules/.bin/jest --passWithNoTests --runInBand --logHeapUsage << parameters.filter >>
```

We then call the `run-tests` job many times, in parallel, with different `filter` values:

```
      - run tests:
          requires:
            - install npm packages
          name: Test feedArea
          filter: --testPathPattern='feedArea.test'

      - run tests:
          requires:
            - install npm packages
          name: Test blackListArea
          filter: --testPathPattern='blackListArea.test'

      - run tests:
          requires:
            - install npm packages
          name: Test projectsAreaV2
          filter: --testPathPattern='projectsAreaV2.test'

      (and so on)
```

This works perfectly. However there's a lot of duplication here.

**Is there a way I can loop through a list of filter values, and run the job with each value?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a matrix. Here's a snippet:

```yaml
workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - tests:
          matrix:
            parameters:
              filter:
                - "--testPathPattern='feedArea.test'"
                - "--testPathPattern='blackListArea.test'"
                - "--testPathPattern='projectsAreaV2.test'"
```

Here's the docs: https://circleci.com/blog/circleci-matrix-jobs/